# Uniform convergence of series, help calculating supremum

Tags: real-analysis

Given the series:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n^2}$$

I'm trying to test it for uniform convergence over R. I'm quite sure that it's not uniformly convergent, as I've done

$f(x) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$

$M_n = sup |f_n(x)| = \infty$

Therefore the series isn't uniformly convergent.

However, I'm not sure if I calculated the supremum correctly. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Here, uniform convergence requires $$a_n:=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left|{x\over n^2}-0\right|\to 0\text{ as }n\to \infty.$$

But, for any fixed $n$, as you surmised,
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left|{x\over n^2}-0\right|=\infty,$$
and thus $a_n\not\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

(In other words, there does not exist a bounded sequence $\{M_n\}$, much less a summable such sequence, if you are working from the contrapositive of the Weierstrass $M$-test.)

Hence the series does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.